# Problem with jquery handling checkboxes in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, safari, checkbox

I am using jquery to locate all the checkboxes in a table column that are checked. For that purpose I am using the following code:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function () {
    //Do Stuff
});
```

This works fine in Firefox 3 but does not work in IE8 or Safari. Can anyone explain why and/or provide a workaround?

EDIT: I'm using jQuery v1.3.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each...`

**Edit** or even sweeter: `$("input:checkbox:checked").each...`

That works for me in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("input:checked").click(function () {
    alert('abc');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround:

```
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    //Do Stuff
});
```